# About websphere mq temporary dynamic queue creator zOS RACF

Tags: ibm-mq

(Websphere MQ, z/OS, RACF) Only the creator of a temporary dynamic queue may delete it with an MQCLOSE.  Given the RACF RESLEVEL profile, is the creator of the queue all (0, 1, or 2) userids prescribed by the access level?

Answer (score 0):

The object handle acquired at open (that created the dynamic temporary queue) is the same as the one used for the close.